# Products list not seen while editing, using form model binding in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.1

In my ecommerce project, I have Product and Carousel Model.

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'code', 'name', 'description', 'special_note', 'sort', 'display', 'weight', 'enquiry'
    ];


    public function carousels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Carousel')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Carousel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Carousel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'display', 'sort'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function getProductListAttribute()
    {
        return $this->products->lists('id');
    }
}
```

Here's the controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $products = Product::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('admin.carousels.create', compact('products'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $carousel = Carousel::create($request->all());

    $carousel->products()->attach($request->input('product_list'));

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $carousel = Carousel::findOrFail($id);

    $products = Product::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('admin.carousels.edit', compact('carousel', 'products'));
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

The carousel form:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'name']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('sort', 'Sort:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('sort', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'sort']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('display', 'Display:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('display', ['Disabled' => 'Disabled', 'Enabled' => 'Enabled'], null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'id' => 'display']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('product_list', 'Products:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('product_list[]', $products, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'multiple']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit($submitButtonText, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block m_top_15', 'id' => $submitButtonId]) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is that, when I use form model binding to edit the carousel form, I get no product displayed in the select box, though I can see all the products to select from. The selected products are not seen for the particular carousel.

What is the mistake that I have made ? Kindly help me out.

Thanks.

**P.S:** I am using Laravel 5.1 and came across this issue for the first time. Earlier I used to do this in Laravel 5 without any issue.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Wondering if my answer regarding the changes to `list()` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to how `lists()` is handled in 5.1. From the upgrade guide -

> The lists Method
>
> The lists method now returns a Collection instance instead of a plain
>   array for Eloquent queries. If you would like to convert the
>   Collection into a plain array, use the all method:
>
> User::lists('id')->all(); Be aware that the Query Builder lists method
>   still returns an array.